# Entity Framework - include multiple collection-properties in 2nd level navigation property throws EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, include, eager-loading

I'm using MySql 6.9.9 in combination with EF 6. I know that if I want to include multiple navigation-properties I just add another include, which works fine.

For Example (works):

```
return _repositoryManager.GetRepository<KundenRepository>().GetSingle(x => x.Id == kundeId,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.AbteilungListe),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen.Laender));
```

Now I have the situation where I want to include a collection to Zuordnungen -> KontakteAddressen (works):

```
return _repositoryManager.GetRepository<KundenRepository>().GetSingle(x => x.Id == kundeId,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.AbteilungListe),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen.Laender),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen).Select(dest => dest.KontakteBemerkungen));
```

And now if I want to include another collection to Zuordnungen -> KontakteAddressen it crashes:

```
return _repositoryManager.GetRepository<KundenRepository>().GetSingle(x => x.Id == kundeId,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter,
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen),
 x => x.KundenSachbearbeiter.Select(dest => dest.Mitarbeiter).Select(dest => dest.AbteilungListe),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen.Laender),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen).Select(dest => dest.KontakteBemerkungen),
 x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.KontakteAddressen).Select(dest => dest.KontakteKommunikation));
```

Additional information:

This is my GetSingle method (I'm using repository pattern):

```
 public virtual TDto GetSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where,
         params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        TDto result;

        using (var context = new Entities(_connectionStringName))
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

            query = navigationProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, navigationProperty) => current.Include(navigationProperty));

            var item = query.AsNoTracking().Where(where).SingleOrDefault(); // Exception happens here

            result = _mapper.Map<TDto>(item);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My Entitymodel:
[Entitymodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3G4P.png)

My datamodel:
[Datamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UHKc.png)

I get an System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

InnerException: 
{"Unknown column 'Extent6.Id' in 'on clause'"}

Details:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException ist aufgetreten.
>     HResult=-2146232004
>     Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>     Source=EntityFramework
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>          at SuR.Runtime.Data.EntityFramework.DataAccess.GenericDataRepository`2.GetSingle(Expression`1 where, Expression`1[] navigationProperties) in C:\Users\Daniel\Source\Repos\SurFramework.git\SuR.Runtime.Data\EntityFramework\DataAccess\GenericRepository.cs:line 84
>     InnerException: 
>          Code=0
>          ErrorCode=-2147467259
>          HResult=-2147467259
>          Message=Unknown column 'Extent6.Id' in 'on clause'
>          Number=1054
>          Source=MySql.Data
>          StackTrace:
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>               at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          InnerException:

**EDIT**

I created the same scenario on MSSQL Database (Also changed the provider in app.config) and it's working perfectly, so I guess it's maybe a bug in MySql provider?

Comment: can you remove this one and test it `x => x.Zuordnungen.Select(dest => dest.RechEmfAddresse).Select(dest => dest.KontakteBemerkungen),` ?

Comment: @Sampath Than it's working. Thing is that if I select more than one collection it crashes. I also found out that if I directly convert ToList() after query.AsNoTracking().ToList(); it's working fine and I get all my results! But  of course this is not a solution because then I have millions of data and filter it in memory.

Comment: why we cannot see `RechEmfAddresse` on your diagrams ?

Comment: Most likely this is a bug in query generation. You should avoid having that many includes anyway, try other [loading strategies](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4678/loading-related-entities#t=201609021032077598976).

Comment: It also can be some mapping problem. If exception occurs at query execution phase, you should be able to look at generated SQL. Just be sure that  generated query is valid

Comment: @AdilMammadov I checked the generated SQL Statements and executed in the DB directly and they are working fine.

Comment: Are you using Oracle as database? If you do, what is the version?

Comment: I use MySql 5.7.10